UNNEST used to SELECT columns
Is it possible to use UNNEST in a SELECT statement for selecting column names?
Consider the groceries table below:
CREATE OR REPLACE TABLE tmp.groceries AS
(
SELECT 
  "milk" AS dairy,
  "eggs" AS protein,
  "bread" AS grain
)

I want to select the protein and dairy columns.  Of course, I could do this via SELECT protein, dairy FROM tmp.groceries.
My question: can I do the above query using UNNEST as below:
SELECT UNNEST(['dairy','protein']) 
FROM tmp.groceries


Motivation: This query is part of a python script.  The table in question is massive and the columns I want differ depending on the application.  In my query `['dairy','protein'] will be a variable to be unnested.

the query is wrong in multiple levels. you have to select * from unnest . then you are trying to unnest an array of string that even are not coming from the cte . in the cte even there is no column with array data type. so what are you trying to do?

Hi @Ottpocket, Could you check this stacklink, which has the usecase of using UNNEST in the SELECT statement ? Let me know if this helps you or not.

@DhirajSingh, the link has the UNNEST after the FROM statement.  I would like it before the FROM statement as a way to select columns.  This does not answer my question.

no you can't!, you have to build your query in python then and then execute it

As @eshirvana noted in the comments, this is not possible.  If you have the same motivation as myself - wanting to dynamically select columns with a python list variable - this is quite possible.  The code below does this.
#inside your python script
import pandas as pd
from google.cloud import bigquery

col_names = ['dairy','protein'] 

query= f"""
    SELECT {', '.join(col_names)}
    FROM tmp.groceries
"""

#get the query as a pandas dataframe
df = bigquery.Client().query(query, location="US").to_dataframe()

